# Construction function

Tags: solidity, javascript, truffle-migration, bignumber

My construction function accepts three arguments, one of which has to be a specific amount written in Wei. Whenever I try to compile and migrate my contract an error shows up notifying me that number is not acceptable and is causing overflowing. I write the number in the migration file like this "15000000000000000000" which is equal to 15 ETH. Does anyone know how can I overcome this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us ur code

Comment: My guess is that you should use BigNumber instead of a literal number

Answer (score 1):

15000000000000000000 is well within `uint256` boundaries, what type did you set for it? If its `uint32` or less the overflow is normal.

Also please when your code throws an error include it directly in your question, it makes answering you way easier.